# Hover.com domain cant be reached

Tags: domain-name-system, domain-name, domain-registrar

I recently bought a .DE domain from Hover.com for use in email addresses (I am using mailbox.org) and also a web service in the future.

The name-servers are set to ns1.hover.com and ns2.hover.com. I have 2 A-records set, one with '*' and one with '@' as host, pointing to hover.com 's IP address (64.98.145.30). These where generated by Hover.
Additionally i have 2 TXT-records, one for SPF ('@' as host), and one to connect the email-service (the host is a key that you get from the email-service to authenticate).

The problem is, that the domain cannot be reached from anywhere, except when I use
`dig actio-search.de @ns1.hover.com`. Otherwise I get NXDOMAIN, or 'Name or service not known'.

I am a complete newbie when it comes to DNS, so is there maybe just some mistake in the config or a conceptual misunderstanding by me so that the domain cannot be resolved?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You need to enable the delegation hence changing the nameservers through your registrar. You would get far better reply if you gave the real name involved.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek The domain is there now. Interestingly the (it's Gernamy so it's minimalist) whois record says `Status: failed`. I've not seen that before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from whois:

```
Domain: actio-search.de
Nserver: ns1.hover.com
Nserver: ns2.hover.com
Status: failed
Changed: 2021-09-21T18:55:10+02:00
```

The Status line is a concern. There is something wrong with your domain. The registry authoritative nameservers do not publish it, so the domain does not exist (does not resolve):

```
$ dig de. ns +short
f.nic.de.
l.de.net.
n.de.net.
s.de.net.
a.nic.de.
z.nic.de.
$ dig @f.nic.de. actio-search.de NS | grep status: | tail -1
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 11411
```

You need to go to your registrar (.de public whois does not show it), where you bought that domain, but you say it is Hover, and make them let you know why is the domain in failed status at registry and how to fix it.